# Mongodb: is possible to returning other value from array with project using `$ne`?

Tags: mongodb

Can mongo `$ne` return value in `$project` instead of `true` or `false` ?

The documents :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1449db6f934a2926c175d1"),
    "clients" : [ 
        "82", 
        "85"
    ],
    "roomId" : 1,
    "message" : [ 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2019-06-27T04:44:49.528Z"),
            "status" : "SEND",
            "text" : "Ellorad",
            "sender" : "82",
            "reciever" : "82",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1449db6f934a2926c175d2")
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2019-06-27T04:44:49.528Z"),
            "status" : "SEND",
            "text" : "helas veronaaah",
            "sender" : "82",
            "reciever" : "85",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1449ff6f934a2926c175d3")
        }
    ]
}
```

What I tried :

```
    Chat.aggregate([
      { $match: { clients: 82 } },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: '$roomId',
          receiver: { $ne: ['$clients', 82] },
          message: { $slice: ['$message', -1] }
        }
      }
    ])
```

The result :

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "receiver": true
      "message": [
        {
          "time": "2019-06-27T04:44:49.528Z",
          "status": "SEND",
          "text": "helas veronaaah",
          "sender": "82",
          "reciever": "85",
          "_id": "5d1449ff6f934a2926c175d3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So the receiver just returning true or false here, which is right considering its `$ne`, but the result that I want is, the receiver here to be '85' not `true` or `false`

Comment: Do you want the receiver to be the other value from clients array, from what is provided? Eg. if `clients:82` it should return 85, and if `clients:85` it should return 82?

Comment: yes the other value, array or not is okay though

Comment: but your clients is an array, in this case : [82,85] . so if 82 is input, it should have 85 in receiver and if 85 is input, it should have 82 in the receiver right?

Comment: yeah I mean the type of result if input 85 then result `receiver: [82] ` or `receiver:82` is okay for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you:

1) `unwind` the clients array, and

2) use `$match` in the next stage to exclude the undesired value(82 in this case),

3) use `$project` stage to get your desired result, `clients` will have your desired `receiver`.

Try this :

```
Chat.aggregate([
  { $match: { clients: 82 } },
  {
      $unwind : "clients"
  },
  {
      $match : {
          clients : {$ne : 82}
      }
  },
  {
      $project : {
            _id: '$roomId',
            receiver: "$clients",
            message: { $slice: ['$message', -1] }
      }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot haven't look on map reduce using `$unwind`